# How to remove browser cookies in a selective fashion

Tags: browser, cookies, user-interface, cross-browser

Is there a tool which will allow me to selectively remove cookies (instead of removing all cookies).

Answer (score 0):

Depend on your question is client-side:
firefox has a nice cookie anager and alot of plugins to manage them

on server-side:

If they've an expire time you can delete selectively setting this time in the past as you can see here:

http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1501/php_delete_or_expire_a_browser_cookie/